# How to find a longer string in an array of shorter ones in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, string, function

In Excel, I have arrays of strings, and I am trying to see if they "match" another array of shorter strings. Looking for a function that will return true\false.

Long Array:

```
A1 7-Zip 22.01 (x64)
A2 Adobe Acrobat
A3 Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)
A4 Adobe Acrobat DC
A5 Adobe Acrobat Reader
```

Short Array:

```
A1 7-Zip
A2 ABS PDF Install
A3 Adobe Acrobat Reader
A4 Adobe Genuine Service
```

For example:

- "Long Array-A1" should match "Short Array-A1"
- "Long Array-A5" should match "Short Array-A3"
- "Long Array-A2" should not match "Short Array-A3"

What I have tried:

```
=MATCH(LOWER("*"&ShortStrings!A2&"*"),LOWER("*"LongStrings!A2:A10"*"),0)
```

Returns:

```
A1 7-Zip 22.01 (x64) - No Match - Should Match Short-A1
A2 Adobe Acrobat - No Match - Good
A3 Adobe Acrobat (64-bit) - No Match - Good
A4 Adobe Acrobat DC - No Match - Good
A5 Adobe Acrobat Reader - Match to A3
```

Comment: in terms of length, "A5 Adobe Acrobat Reader" is the same as "A3 Adobe Acrobat Reader".

Comment: So have you tried vlookup() or match() ?

Comment: Closest I have gotten was "=MATCH(LOWER("*"&LongStrings!A2&"*"),LOWER("*"&ShortStrings!$A$2:$A$10&"*"),0)"

But it only hits for exact matches, not what I am looking for

Comment: You should add your attempt to the original question with any info about what it fails to do.

Comment: Is any match of the shorter string always at the beginning of the longer string or can it be in the middle or at the end?

Comment: Updated what I have and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&ShortStrings!$A$1:$A$4&"*",LongStrings!A1,0)))
```

[image]

Or:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ShortStrings!$A$1:$A$4,LongStrings!A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ended up using your second option, but had to switch the lists around.

`=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&ShortStrings!$A$1:$A$5&"*",LongStrings!A1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up tweaking one of the submissions slightly to get it to work.

```
Psuedo code
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&ShortStrings!$A$1:$A$5&"*",LongStrings!A1)))

Real code
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&Table15[Excluded Name]&"*",A2)))
```

Long Strings:
[Long Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IK2j.png)

Short Strings:
[Short Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDPDI.png)

Thank you for the help everyone !